# Position when inserting in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, std, stdmap

I have a method which inserts a pair in std::map.
The map is something like (0, value0), (3, value3), (8, value8) ...
So when I insert I need to specify the integer value.
My problem is that if I have:
(0, value0), (3, value3) and I want to insert (5, value5) with value3 same as value5 the pair (5, value5) must not be inserted.
How could I check that the previous position to the position where my element should go does not have same value?
So far I have tried to insert the pair, get the iterator, check previous value and remove the inserted value if needed. But I find that solution kind of ugly.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that you want value as key

Comment: If you consider `{3, value3}`, `{5, value3}`, and `{5, value3}`, `{5, value5}` equivalent, then `{3, value3}`, `{5, value5}` should also be equivalent...

Comment: @RuLoViC : if you want to keep this structure, maybe you can store the values (value0, value2, ...) in another vector and check if the've been inserted before inserting pair in you map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map's `lower_bound` function will return an iterator to the first element whose position is greater than or equal to the one you give it; then you can go back one. (Carefully, in case you're already at the start.)

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound

Comment: Thanks Alan, this was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: BTW: You can pass the returned iterator as a hint to a subsequent `insert`, if you choose to do one, to get O(1) rather than O(log N) insertion - you've already paid the lookup cost.